# jqGrid groupHeaders problems

Tags: jqgrid

I am a newer to jqGrid, I want to generate groupHeaders in dynamic way, but it did work, The getValues('department') statement is analysis the department which user input, for example 'a,b,c'.The code as forrow:

```
function search() {
        var startDate = $('#startDate').val();
        var endDate = $('#endDate').val();
        var department = getValues('department');

        var colName = new Array();
        var colAttr = new Array();
        colName[0] = "日期";
        colAttr[0] = "{name:'" + colName[0] + "',sortable:false,align:'center'}"

        var length = getLength(department);
        for (var i = 1; i < length + 1; i++) {
            colName[2 * i - 1] = "咨询" + i;
            colName[2 * i] = "投诉" + i;
            colAttr[2 * i - 1] = "{name:'" + colName[2 * i - 1] + "'index:'" + i + "',sortable:false,align:'center'}";
            colAttr[2 * i] = "{name:'" + colName[2 * i] + "',sortable:false,align:'center'}";
        }
        var header = mySplitter(department);

        var urlStr = '<%=jspName%>?startDate=' + startDate + '&endDate=' + endDate + '&action=query&department=' + department;
        urlStr = encodeURI(urlStr);
        jQuery("#dataGrid").clearGridData();
        jQuery("#dataGrid").GridUnload();
        jQuery("#dataGrid").jqGrid({
            url: urlStr,
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: colName,
            colModel: colAttr,
            height: 450,
            rowNum: 20000,                    //默认每页记录数
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],          //可选择的每页记录数
            pager: '#dataPager',
            shrinkToFit: true,
            hidegrid: false,
            emptyrecords: "暂无数据",
            viewrecords: true,
            loadonce: true, //自动翻页
            caption: "<%=title%>"
        });
        jQuery("#dataGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#dataPager', {edit: false, add: false, del: false, autowidth: true});
        $("#dataGrid").setGridWidth($(window).width() * 0.90);
        jQuery("#dataGrid").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
            useColSpanStyle: true,
            groupHeaders: header
        });
    }

function mySplitter(str) {
        if (str === null) {
            return null;
        }
        var temp;
        temp = str.split(",");
        var result = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < temp.length - 1; i++) {
            result[i] = "{startColumnName: '" + (i + 1) + "', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: '" + temp[i] + "'}";
        }
        return result;
    }

    function getLength(str) {
        if (str === null) {
            return 0;
        }
        var temp = str.split(",");
        return temp.length - 1;

    }
```

The code didn't generate groupHeaders. Is anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Elements of `colModel` array have to be objects with properties `name` etc. Instead of that you set *strings* as elements of `colAttr`.

In JavaScript you should never use `new Array()` instead of that you should use `[]`:

```js
var colName = ["日期"],
    colAttr = [{name: colName[0], sortable:false, align: 'center'}],
    i;
```

If you need to append array with new item it's better to use `push` method.

Additionally you should

- remove `index` property from all `colModel` items. You use `loadonce: true`. So you will be able to use local sorting after removing `index` properties.
- if you need define the some properties for all columns you should better remove the duplicates from `colModel` items (remove `sortable:false,align:'center'`) and add jqGrid option `cmTemplate` with the settings. For example you can use `cmTemplate: { sortable: false, align: "center" }`.
- I recommend you to add `gridview: true` and `autoencode: true` options. Additionally you should consider to use `height: "auto"` instead of `height: 450`.
- I recommend you to use `postData` with functions as properties instead of building `urlStr` manually (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935) for details). In the case the options could be

```js
url: '<%=jspName%>',
postData: {
    startDate: function () { return $("#startDate").val(); },
    endDate: function () { return $("#endDate").val(); },
    action: "query",
    department: function () { return getValues('department'); }
}
```